# Whats wrong with this python code? I get an error after I input

Tags: python, string, variables

```
while print('Type ROLL to roll for your stats.'):
    roll = input() # I get my error right after I input
    if roll == "roll" or roll == "ROLL":
        strength = random.randint(1, 100)
        defense = random.randint(1, 100)
        attack = random.randint(1, 100)
    print('Your attack level is ' + attack + '.')
    print('Your strength level is ' + strength + '.')
    print('Your defense level is ' + defense + '.')
    print('Would you like to reroll?')
    reroll = input()
    if reroll == no or reroll == NO:
        break
```

My error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
roll
NameError: name 'roll' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x? The `input()` function is different in each version.

Comment: `if reroll == no or reroll == NO:` - what is _that?_

Comment: @paxdiablo - *that* is the next SO question by this OP.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the code before running it? How did you run the code? What did you input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here and there:

- Your while loop won't work, since the return value of `print` is `None`.  It won't execute, which I don't think is what was intended.  You can change that to an indefinite loop by `while True` or `while 1`.  Your code *will*, in theory, break out of the loop when someone enters 'no', but we'll get to that...
- You can change your `input()` statements to contain the text you want to display in the terminal before they enter a value.  For example, you can change one of them to `roll = input('Type ROLL to roll for your stats.)`
- Neither `no` nor `NO` are defined as variables.  Remember, they need to be *strings* in order for them to be evaluated, since that is what you are looking for.  In the future, it may be advantageous to look into a statement such as `if reroll.lower() == 'no'`, since that will save repeated typing on multiple string entry values.

Hopefully these get you on the right track.  Don't forget, if you see an answer you like here, feel free to accept it (so the community knows you've got your answer).

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be using Python 2.x, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. You may be following a tutorial designed for Python 3.x.

Comment: Well, the behaviour you have described is consistent with Python 2.x. What happens if you try `raw_input` instead?

Comment: Sorry, no. `raw_input` will *not* cause the same problem as you showed, whether you are in Python 2.x or Python 3.x (you will get no error in Python 2.x and a *different* error in Python 3.x, because `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3.x). Make sure you are actually running the modified code that you think you're running.

Comment: `raw_input` just reads a string from standard input. So, as @GregHewgill said, there is no way you could get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

`roll = eval(input())`

or

`import sys
roll = sys.stdin.readline()`

according to:
http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/

Comment: Brian, eval(input()) is a way to get the Python3 input to act like the Python2 one. I'm not sure it's relevant here.

Comment: You're right, that eval doesn't make any sense.  Thanks for the insight, I'm working through the 2/3 transition...

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, using the [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) command causes the error you describe:

```
>>> blah = input()
roll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'roll' is not defined
```

For Python 2, you would use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input):

```
>>> blah = raw_input()
roll
>>> print blah
roll
```

In Python 3, the first example works fine - `raw_input` was renamed to [`input`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) - maybe you ran the wrong command accidentally? You could verify this by doing:

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

..in your script somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
roll = input('Type ROLL to roll for your stats. ')
if roll == "roll" or roll == "ROLL":
    #do your stats roll here
reroll = input('Would you like to reroll? ')
if reroll == 'no' or reroll == 'NO':
    break
```

I believe that your error most likely comes from the fact that you are printing the question, and then passing a blank input() function. When you are using the input function you should be typing your question as a string within the parentheses.

```
input('Place your question / prompt here, with a space at the end so there is a gap between the question and your input: ')
```

Additionally, when you test if reroll is equal to no or NO, you have to remember that the words no and NO **must** be in quotation marks to denote a string! Python sees anything that is not in quotation marks as either a number, variable, function or reserved word (like OR). If you have not already declared no and NO as a variable your program will not work. Therefore, you must either put single or double quotes around the words no and NO, or at the start of the program you must declare them as variables, e.g.

```
no = 'no'
NO = 'NO'
```

Also, the while loop is broken. For an infinite loop set the first statement to `While True`. If you would like the loop to break when a certain condition is met, declare another variable before the loop begins and set its value to `True` (the boolean true, not the word true). Once this is done, you can set that variable to the boolean value `False` to exit the loop

```
rolling = True
While rolling:
    #do stuff
If exitcondition == True:
    rolling = False # When exitcondition is True, rolling is False and the loop is broken
```